# Suddenly can't paste or create files to any other drive. (Xubuntu dual boot with freshly installed Windows 10)

Tags: xubuntu, paste

I have 2 hard drives on automount that I could access perfectly. Then I installed Windows 10 and repaired GRUB to get dual boot. I don't know if that's the cause but now I can't paste any files into any drive other than my Xubuntu partition. I googled it but didn't find a solution so I really need some help here. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can't paste why? What happens when you try? The paste button doesn't work? The mouse gets disabled? The screen goes black? Is there a permission problem? Are there errors?

Comment: Paste button was blanked out but found and fixed the issue, see answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And of course I find the solution minutes after I post the question.

I just had to go to the Power Settings in Windows and UNCHECK fast startup.

I hope this will help another poor soul in the future.